# Run: main.dart tab is empty in Android Studio - not showing buttons or print logs

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

Using flutter with Android Studio, the main.dart tab as per below is just greyed out. The buttons (hot restart etc) and print logs no longer show. I have no idea how to get these back. Please help!

[image]

Comment: (right click  ,uncheck pause output)

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to fix this issue. I deleted Android Studio and downloaded and re-installed the latest version and also installed all the recommended updates that popped up, and the main.dart tab was back to normal again.

Not why it stopped working, buy fyi if anyone else encounters this problem.